# Hide android keyboard when tapping somewhere other than edittext in alertdialog

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I want to hide the keyboard in an alertdialog when I click somewhere that's not in an edittext. I have been looking good answer on stackoverflow and google, but I haven't found one yet. So could you please help me. I've got an alertDialog layout with 4 edittext boxes and I want to close keyboard if I tap outside them.

I hope you can help me guys and this one isn't duplicated answer, because others weren't working for me and they weren't for alertdialog.

Thank you,
Cheers :}

Comment: checking the focus and hiding the keyboard may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bhargav Jhaveri

I edited your code:

```
   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(test.this); //created a dialog
    LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01); //This is dialog layout
    final EditText editText=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.edt1);  //this is edittext in dialog
    linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(v == relAppointment1) { //What is relAppointment1, variable is undefined
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context
                        .INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But what is relAppointment1?

Thank you for answering. Please check my code, is everything right?
Cheers :]

Answer (score 0):

Let us say the parent Layout is LinearLayout in which you have the EditText.

So find the ID of the Linear Layout.

linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout) from XML.

```
linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(v == relAppointment1) {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context
                                .INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Hope this will resolve the issue.